# How to configure JBoss 7 to serve different default war for specific hostnames (with SSL)

Tags: ssl-certificate, jboss7.x, hostname

Here is my use case.

I want to use JBoss 7 to serve 2 different webapps (war) depending on the hostname which is used inside the HTTP request :

- When I access to https://app1.mydomain.com/, JBoss must serve `app1.war` with the SSL certificate "app1.mydomain.com"
- When I access to https://app2.mydomain.com/, JBoss must serve `app2.war` with the SSL certificate "app2.mydomain.com"

I would prefer that the `appX.war` were used as root context for each hostname (accessing to https://appX.mydomain.com/index.html would use the `appX.war/index.html` file), but I could accept going to https://appX.mydomain.com/appX/ to access my `appX` (`X` is `1` or `2`).

Moreover I would want to use a single IP & port for that configuration, but this seems to be not possible (according to [that SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343059/535203) & [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10173447/535203) and [that thread on JBoss forum](https://community.jboss.org/thread/200761)) without using [Appache HTTPD](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI) as a proxy. It would be the alternative but I would prefer not using it.

I tried to configure that with the `standalone` mode (and by using different IP). Here is an extract from my `standalone.xml` :

```xml
...
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="app1.mydomain.com" native="true">
        <connector name="https-app1" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="app1-https" secure="true">
            <ssl password="pass1" certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/cert/app1.mydomain.com.key" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="false" certificate-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/cert/app1.mydomain.com.crt"/>
        </connector>
        <connector name="https-app2" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="app2-https" secure="true">
            <ssl password="pass2" certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/cert/app2.mydomain.com.key" protocol="TLSv1" verify-client="false" certificate-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/cert/app2.mydomain.com.crt"/>
        </connector>
        <virtual-server name="app1.mydomain.com" enable-welcome-root="false" default-web-module="app1">
            <alias name="app1.mydomain.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
        <virtual-server name="app2.mydomain.com" enable-welcome-root="false" default-web-module="app2">
            <alias name="app2.mydomain.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
...
<interfaces>
    <interface name="app1.mydomain.com">
        <inet-address value="10.0.0.1"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="app2.mydomain.com">
        <inet-address value="10.0.0.2"/>
    </interface>
...
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="app1-https" interface="app1.mydomain.com" port="443" fixed-port="true"/>
    <socket-binding name="app2-https" interface="app2.mydomain.com" port="443" fixed-port="true"/>
...
```

But that not seems to work as expected...

- When I access to https://app1.mydomain.com/ I see my welcome file of my `app1.war` (I think this is due to the `default-virtual-server` attribute)
- When I access to https://app1.mydomain.com/app1/ I see a 404 report (with HTML body content)
- When I access to https://app1.mydomain.com/app2/ I see my welcome file of my `app2.war`
- When I access to https://app2.mydomain.com/, https://app2.mydomain.com/app1/ or https://app2.mydomain.com/app2/, JBoss only answers an HTTP "404 Not Found" without any body HTML content, so my page is blank.

Does anyone has an idea ?

(I've also posted [that question to the JBoss user forum](https://community.jboss.org/message/783847))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, as it seems it's not possible directly using JBoss 7, I've used Apache HTTPD, non root context for my apps, and multiple IPs (the worst I would wanted) :

```
...
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
...
Listen 80
Listen 443
...

<VirtualHost IP1:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
    ServerName app1.mydomain.com:80
    ServerAlias www.app1.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/app1.mydomain.com-error.log"
    TransferLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/app1.mydomain.com-access.log"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://app1.mydomain.com/$1 [R]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost IP1:443>

    #   General setup for the virtual host
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
    ServerName app1.mydomain.com:443
    ServerAlias www.app1.mydomain.com
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/app1.mydomain.com-error.log"
    TransferLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/app1.mydomain.com-access.log"

    ProxyPass /app1 ajp://localhost:8009/app1
    ProxyPassReverse /app1 https://app1.mydomain.com/app1

    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteRule ^/$ /app1/ [R]

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5  

    #   Server Certificate:
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/SSL/app1.mydomain.com.crt" 
    #   Server Private Key:
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/SSL/app1.mydomain.com.key"
    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    SSLCertificateChainFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/SSL/ca-root.crt"

    #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    #   Per-Server Logging:
    #   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
    #   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
    CustomLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/app1.mydomain.com-ssl.log" "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

That's for `app1`.

For `app2`, just duplicate this configuration and replace `app1` with `app2` and `IP1` with `IP2`.

Answer (score 1):

*I believe that you have two options.*

**Option 1: Using JBoss Virtual Hosts**

In order to do this, you must add virtual host entries to the web sub service. Which you were doing.

I think the part that you missed was adding `<virtual-host>` tags to your `jboss-web.xml` files within your web apps.

Please reference the following link for quick instructions on setting up
[Virtual Hosts With JBoss AS7](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VirtualHostsWithJBossAS7).

**Option 2: Using Apache**

This would be the method I prefer, especially for a production use case. You have Apache be your web server and you have it proxy incoming requests to JBoss.  Apache will also take care of SSL.

For example you can do this through mod_jk, which is a load balancer.  mod_jk directs traffic to your application via the AJP connector, which should be available using the HA profiles in JBoss.

Since you are using mod_jk and HA profiles, you can go ahead and cluster your applications and load balance those clusters if you would like.

*Please let me know if you have any further questions.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jyore but, for your "Option 1", the `<virtual-host>` in `jboss-web.xml` in webapps is optional according to [your link](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VirtualHostsWithJBossAS7), so I'm still stuck here. For your "Option 2", we know that & we would prefer not to use it because it adds one more potential flaw in the server... but I think as JBoss 7 seems to be buggy for those virtual hosts things, we will use the `mod_proxy_ajp` of Apache with an AJP connector (you don't need the HA profile by the way, in the default you can add an AJP port in the `socket-binding-group`)

Comment: Yes you can add the AJP connector, was saying that it is already available in HA profile and that makes clustering available too...after rereading my post, I see how I did not make that completely clear :)